# Unzip all zip files in a target folder?

Tags: 12.04, zip, curl, unzip

I have a curl cronjob which periodically downloads a bunch of zip files into a target folder. Like this:

```
curl www.zipdownloadfile.com/file.zip > file.zip
```

Now I need to have Ubuntu unzip all of the zip files in that target folder.

What's the proper command which will unzip all of the files in a target destination/folder?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

thats your command man this will unzip all zip file in a destination file

```
find /path-to-folder -name '*.zip' -exec unzip -d destination_folder {} +
```

Just try it .

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that `unzip *.zip` doesn't work for some reason. I guess the unzip doesn't accept wildcard path arguments for files.

Nux's answer is good but I use a slightly different version of the find command. If you cd into the folder you've downloaded all the zip files then you can just run:

`find . -type f -name "*.zip" -exec unzip {} \;`

This will search the current working directory and all sub-directories recursively with `.`, then find only files, `-type f`, then search for anything named *.zip `with`-name`and it will execute unzip`exec unzip`and substitute the result of the search which is the full file name and place it with`{}`after the unzip command as the argument.`\;` is just magical syntax to say 'I'm done the command is finished.'.

This still worked for me in Ubuntu 16.04 to unzip all files in the current directory after downloading a huge number.

A similar command can also used to unrar a set of rar files you've downloaded simultaneously as well:

`find . -type f -name "*.rar" -exec unrar x -e {} \;`

The above magical command will search all files in the current directory and all folders and files recursively in sub-directories to find all files that end in `.rar` and then unrar them directly to the current working directory.

Let's say you want to unpack a bunch of stuff that you've just recently downloaded:

```
Fri Nov 17 10:56 AM Downloads: tree .
.
├── download1
│   ├── show01.r00
│   ├── show01.r01
│   ├── show01.r02
│   └── show01.rar
├── download2
│   ├── movie01.r00
│   ├── movie01.r01
│   ├── movie01.r02
│   ├── movie01.r03
│   └── movie01.rar
└── download3
    ├── program01.r00
    ├── program01.r01
    ├── program01.r02
    ├── program01.r03
    └── program01.rar

3 directories, 14 files
```

This is only a small example you could have 20 or even 40 different foldedrs each containing their own master .zip file or .rar file that needs to be unrar'd. Doing a CD into each individual download directory to use 'unrar' is both time consuming and wasteful. Just use the find command!

```
sudo apt-get install unzip
sudo apt-get install unrar
cd ~/Downloads
find . -type f -name "*.rar" -exec unrar x -e {} \;
find . -type f -name "*.zip" -exec unzip {} \;
```