# How do I gunzip all files recursively in a target directory?

Tags: extract, gzip

I'd like to know what is the command to use to gunzip all files in a target directory recursively? I tried to use the unzip command but it didn't work.

I tried the command from [Unzip all zip files in a target folder?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/399951/unzip-all-zip-files-in-a-target-folder)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Using the commands below. Replace `<path_of_your_zips>` with the path to your ZIP files and `<out>` with your destination folder:

- For GZ files

  ```
  find <path_of_your_zips> -type f -name "*.gz" -exec tar xf {} -C <out> \;
  ```

  or

  ```
  find <path_of_your_zips> -type f -name "*.gz" -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} tar xf {} -C <out>
  ```
- For ZIP files

  ```
  find <path_of_your_zips> -type f -name "*.zip" -exec unzip {} -d <out> \;
  ```

  or

  ```
  find <path_of_your_zips> -type f -name "*.zip" -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} unzip {} -d <out>
  ```

Comment: Does this work with .gz files?

Comment: improved, Now yes :)

Comment: Why not `-exec` like `find . -type f -name "*.gz" -exec tar xzf {} -C <out> \;`?

Comment: work only for tarball files, not for only g-zipped ones

Comment: gzipped files which are not tar files give this error: `tar: This does not look like a tar archive`

Comment: This method will flatten any folder hierarchy, and is unnecessarily complex. gunzip -r . should be the accepted answer here.

Answer (score 90):

`gunzip` has `-r` option. From `man gunzip` :

```
   -r --recursive
          Travel  the directory structure recursively. If any of the 
file names specified on the command line are directories, gzip 
will descend into the directory and compress all the files it finds
there (or decompress them in  the  case  of gunzip ).
```

So, if you want to `gunzip` all compressed files (`gunzip` can currently decompress files created by gzip, zip, compress, compress -H or pack) inside the directory `/foo/bar` and all its subdirectories :

```
gunzip -r /foo/bar
```

This will handle file names with spaces too.